# Determine the point of intersection between $f(x) = x^2$ and its normal in the point $(a, a^2)$

Tags: calculus

Determine the point of intersection between $f(x) = x^2$ and its normal in the point $(a, a^2)$

**Answer:**

This should be easy enough...

$f'(x) = 2x$

The tangent line in the point $(a, a^2)$ is $y - a^2 = 2 (x - a) \rightarrow y = 2x + a^2 - 2a$

The equation for the normal line is: $y - a^2 = -\frac{1}{2}(x - a) \rightarrow y = -\frac{1}{2}x + a^2 + \frac{1}{2}a$

Now to determine the point of intersection we just see when $f(x)$ and the normal line is equal, i.e.

$x^2 = -\frac{1}{2}x + a^2 + \frac{1}{2}a$

But this seems like a nonsense equation...

Comment: The slope of the tangent line is $2a$ and the slope of the normal line is $-\frac{1}{2a}$. It looks like you are using $2$ for the slope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tangent slope of $f(x)$ at $x = a$ is $f'(a) = 2a$, so you will need to amend the tangent and normal line accordingly.

Normal line is $y - a^2 = -\dfrac{1}{2a}(x - a)$ or $y = -\dfrac{x}{2a}+\dfrac{1}{2}+a^2$.

Set $f(x) = y$, so $x^2 = -\dfrac{x}{2a}+\dfrac{1}{2}+a^2$ or $2ax^2 + x - (a + 2a^3) = 0$. Finish with the quadratic formula

$x = \dfrac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+4(2a)(a+2a^3)}}{4a} = \dfrac{-1 \pm \sqrt{16a^4 + 8a^2 + 1}}{4a}=\dfrac{-1 \pm \sqrt{(4a^2 + 1)^2}}{4a}$

Comment: Of course, one can simplify the first expression a good deal.

Comment: "an exercise left to the reader"

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The slope of the normal line is going to be: $-\frac{1}{2a}$.

set $g(x)=-\frac{1}{2a}x+(a^2+\frac{1}{2})$

You want to solve $g(x)=f(x)$.

$-\frac{1}{2a}x+(a^2+\frac{1}{2})=x^2$

$x^2+\frac{1}{2a}x+\frac{1}{16a^2}=(a^2+\frac{1}{2})+\frac{1}{16a^2}$

$x=\pm\sqrt{(a^2+\frac{1}{2})+\frac{1}{16a^2}}-\frac{1}{4a}$

Personally, I prefer vectors, but it amounts to the same thing:

$(a,a^2)+t[-2a,1]=(x,x^2)$

$a^2+t=(a(1-2t))^2$

And you can solve in this way to get a $t$, which **I** think is more intuitive, and less "symbol pushy"